# Modular arithmetic system of equations.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve a system as follows... 
The $E_i$ are known and the $n_i$ are  known. I need to solve for a unique $x$ that I know exists.

$$ E_1 \cong x  mod  n_1$$

$$ E_2 \cong x  mod  n_2$$

$$ E_3 \cong x  mod  n_3$$

$$ E_4 \cong x  mod  n_4$$

$$ E_5 \cong x  mod  n_5$$

I am not sure what I need to do... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [*Chinese Remainder Theorem*](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/crt.pdf)? See the examples at that link or use Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I am a little bit. That is what I am trying to figure out in a way... Is there an equation that solves that?

Comment: Can I say 


E1 = x mod n1 is the same as E1 mod n1 =x?

Comment: Yes, it is normally understood to mean $E_1  \pmod{n_1} \equiv x  \pmod{n_1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem can solve this kind of system. [Proof and how to use CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) One can also use the sage command CRT.